# How do I construct transition table for the following?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

[Fig. contains transition diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okkyb.jpg)Design Finite Automata which accepts only those strings that start with 1 and ends with 0. Please describe me how to construct transition table because all I need to learn is transition table itself as I can then draw transition diagram from the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from your description we need four states:

- A start state $s_\epsilon$, it signals that nothing has been read
- A state $s_0$ that signals that the word started with a $1$, and the last read symbol was a $0$.
- A state $s_1$ that signals that the word started with a $1$, and the last read symbol was a $1$.
- A state $s_\bot$ that signals that the word started with a $0$.

If we have started with a $0$, nothing ever read can lead to an accepted word, that is we stay in $s_\bot$, that gives the transition table
$$
  \begin{array}{c|*4c}
                 & s_\epsilon & s_0 & s_1 & s_\bot\\ \hline
               0 &  s_\bot    & s_0 & s_0 & s_\bot\\ 
               1 & s_1        & s_1 & s_1 & s_\bot    
  \end{array} 
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here, you have mentioned 4 states but in my text book it says there are 3 states that is A,B and C where they have drawn transition diagram but transition table is not provided, so can you please explain it accordingly? I want to know how transition table is created.

Comment: You have a transition diagram? Can you add it to your question? And - as it stands - an automaton that does what you want needs four states.

Comment: Yes. I have added a link to the description.

Comment: So your description of automata allows for the transition function to be undefined at some points. Note that $\delta(A, 0)$ is not defined. The "undefined state" I called $s_\bot$, in your case, we can read of the transition table from the diagram, giving:
$$ \begin{array}{c|*3c} & A & B & C \\ \hline 0 & \bot & C & C\\
                                                                     1 & B    & B  & B\end{array}$$
So my $s_\epsilon$ corresponds to $A$, my $s_0$ to $C$ and $s_1$ to $B$.

Comment: I know because when I drew the diagram then in state A if i read 0 it goes to state C and according to my text book state A has no 0. Thanks for making it clear. Need to practice creating transition table. Can you please tell me what are the steps to create transition table from a given question?